# Передача данных между устройствами

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте!

Столкнулся с такой задачей: есть два устройства - А и Б, они находятся в одной Wi-Fi сети. Из А в Б надо передать данные (например, base64 строка). Сначала А ищет поддерживаемые устройства в сети, затем перед получением устройство Б должно спросить пользователя, мол, принять данные или нет. Каждое устройство должно выступать в роли **и** передатчтка, **и** приёмника.

Вопрос: как можно это реализовать? С подобной задачей сталкиваюсь в первый раз. В гугле был, но ничего дельного найти не смог (наверное, плохо искал), везде этот NFC. Что-то слышал про сокеты, может быть, стоит копать в их сторону?

**Update 0**: WiFi Direct тоже не подойдёт, так как нужна поддержка 2.3+.
**Update 1**: В данный момент смог решить проблему поиска устройств. Обычный код выложу днём, а сейчас напишу псевдокод:
1. Получаем внутренний IP устройства (лично у меня это `192.168.1.12`)
2. Отсекаем последнее число, теперь можно делаем диапазон IP: `192.168.1.1—192.168.1.255`
3. В цикле подключаемся к каждому IP с помощью `InetAddress`,
далее у объекта `InetAddress` вызываем `isReachable(int timeout)`, если `true`, значит в сети есть девайс с таким именем. В моём случае программа пытается "спросить" у найденного клиента, есть ли на нём моя программа.
**Update 2**: Читаю документацию по сокетам, с каждым перечитыванием становится чуточку понятнее :) Обязательно отпишусь о прогрессе!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбиваем задачу на две части - поиск устройств и передача данных. С передачей данных вопросов не должно возникать - если айпи-порт известен, то подключиться и послать данные можно.

С первой частью также давно существует решение. Называется оно ZeroConf, оно же Avahi, оно же Bonjour (это все одно и то же, просто часть названий запатентирована, поэтому и такая гонка).

Для андроида (да и для java) есть готовая библиотека - [jmdns](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/). В айфонах/маках оно из коробки. Говорят, что в новых андроидах оно также из коробки.

Суть работы протокола. Он работает в два этапа. В первом случае каждый участник сети рассылает udp посылки с короткой информацией о себе, а потом по запросу от одного участника другой может выдать вторую порцию информации, где уже будет и ip.
Там можно вставлять свои пользовательские поля и передавать свою специфичную информацию.

Этот протокол очень широко используется, поэтому он достаточно хорошо протестирован. Примеры реального использования - AirDrop, поиск принтеров в сети.

Answer (score 0):

В сети можно отправить широковещательный пакет (или как-то так называется), чтобы получили все айпишники, находящиеся в этой сети. Не знаю, как это сделать на Java, но думаю, что когда одному устройству нужно найти другое, оно может отправить такой пакет, пока другое будет слушать сеть на наличие таких пакетов.

Comment: @metalurgus, обновил пост.